# Error after installing QtCreator in Arch Linux: cannot open shared object file libicui18n.so.53

Tags: arch-linux, qt

I installed QtCreator on Arch Linux and am now getting this error when trying to start the program:

`qtcreator: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.53: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I am not sure where to go with this. The [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/qt) seemed pretty straight forward regarding the installation of `qtcreator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely is that your system is out-of-date – you have an older `icu` package than QtCreator was built with. (`pacman -Q icu` to check – it should say 53.1-1.)

**Always upgrade** all existing packages when installing new ones, and *at least* once a week (icu 53 has been out for at least a month):

```
# pacman -Syu
```

Comment: You got it. `icu 52.1-1` is what returned. What exactly is that statement doing? I understand `-Q` is query, but do the remaining parameters specify a query and return of all installed packages with %icu% contained within their names?

Comment: @sherrellbc: No, just the installed package with the exact name `icu`.

Comment: I am currently working to update all packages via pacman sync. If this does not resolve the issue, how may I explicitly upgrade only the `icu` package?

Comment: @sherrellbc: [Partial upgrades are explicitly not supported](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported); but technically it is done by just installing the package normally.